# Moving user inputs to a different file from main game file. (Pygame). Positional Arugement error "Takes 1 positional arugement but two where given

Tags: python, class, methods, pygame, typeerror

Created an instance from a Class in a different file from the main file -

```
self.movement = User_input_responses(self)
```

Called a method in that instanced Class to react to users movements -

```
self.movement.user_input_reactions()
```

Error I Got -

> TypeError: User_input_responses.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I tried to move user inputs key reactions out of the main game code because it was making the main game code too hectic. I already had the game working before the move.

Everything i moved over to new file -
method to deal with pygame events
method to deal with user keydown events
method to deal with user keyup events

Code of Main file -

```
from ship_movement import User_input_responses
from settings import Settings
from ship_test import Ship

class Alien_Invasion:

    def __init__(self):
    
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        #screen
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width , self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption(("Alien Invader"))
        self.bg_color = self.settings.bg_color

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.movement = User_input_responses(self)

    def update_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

    def game(self):
        while True:
            self.movement.user_input_reactions()
            self.ship.ship_movement()
            self.update_screen()
            self.clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_launcher = Alien_Invasion()
    game_launcher.game()
```

Code of mentioned Class file -

```
class User_input_responses:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def user_input_reactions(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.keydown(event)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self.keyup(event)
```

Comment: When you call the class constructor you don't pass `self` explicitly.

Comment: If the contructor is supposed to take a reference to the instance that called it, then the problem is that you didn't provide a parameter for that in the `__init__()` method. Another common cause of errors like this is mistyping `__init__`.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Moving it into a different file shouldn't affect any of this.

Comment: i added more code for clarification

Comment: Your indentation is all messed up. The method definitions have to be indented.

Comment: The `User_input_responses` class constructor doesn't take any parameters. As I mentioned above, the `self` parameter is passed automatically, you don't write it explicitly when calling. It doesn't refer to the caller instance, it's the new instance that's being created.

Comment: So it should be `self.movement = User_input_responses()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'User_input_responses' object has no attribute 'screen'

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to access the `screen` attribute of a `User_input_responses` object. I see `self.screen` in the `Alien_Invasion` class.

Comment: And `self.settings.screen`. But `self.settings` is a `Settings` object. not `User_input_responses`.

Comment: Are you going to fix the indentation in your code snippets, or am I just wasting my time here?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): --> game_launcher = Alien_Invasion()  -->  self.movement = User_input_responses() --> self.ship = Ship(self) --> self.screen = game.screen --> AttributeError: 'User_input_responses' object has no attribute 'screen'

Comment: You haven't posted the `Ship` code. Why do you expect the `game` object to have a `screen` attribute?

Comment: You need to take a step back and clearly understand the relationships between all your classes and the parameters you're passing between them.

Comment: I've answered your original question below. If you have other problems, post a new question.

Comment: It seems like `Ship` expects its constructor argument to be a `Game` instance, but you're passing a `User_input_responses` instance instead when you call `self.ship = Ship(self)`

Comment: I dont know why 'User_input_responses' is asking for attribute 'screen' when i dont explicitly use it in the file. I assume since its controlling the movement on the screen it needs access to it. When i put 'self' in 'User_input_responses() it gives access to 'Alien_Invasion' screen but then i get the original error for which i posted this for.

Comment: You haven't shown the code, but I'm guessing you have something like `class Ship(): def __init__(self, game): self.screen = game.screen`. So `game` is the argument you pass when you do `self.ship = Ship(self)`, and that's the `User_input_responses` object.

Comment: I think you don't have a good understanding of how `self` works in Python classes. You need to read a good tutorial on python OOP. I can't teach you here.

Comment: I see what your saying. Thats exactly how my ship_test code starts. Il create another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self` argument is passed automatically, you shouldn't provide an explicit argument when calling the class constructor function. Change

```
self.movement = User_input_responses(self)
```

to

```
self.movement = User_input_responses()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use any arguments because the `self` argument doesn't need an argument so, you change change `self.movement = User_input_responses(self)`
to `self.movement = User_input_responses()`